# Why does the Zephyr need a rotating ring when artificial gravity exists?

Tags: battlestar-galactica, battlestar-galactica-2004

In the 2004 Battestar Galactica, there is a civilian ship called [the Zephyr](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Zephyr) that has a rotating ring section.  This is one of the known methods for creating artificial gravity in space:

[image: Zephyr]

But Battlestar has artificial gravity in place in other ships in universe; people walk on the ground normally on Galactica and Colonial One, which are both rather linear ships.  There are even [two cannon references to gravity controls](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Gravity_in_the_Re-imagined_Series).  So, given they have some ability to generate artificial gravity in space ships, why would the Zephyr have the rotating ring design?

Comment: Perhaps the ship was old enough to pre-date artificial gravity?  Or perhaps the grav field has a steep gradient - it works at human scale but trees can't grow in it.

Comment: @DavidW Cloud9 had indoor trees despite also having a flat layout.

Comment: "*Its enormous ring section was designed in the days when artificial gravity was too expensive to utilize on a commercial ship of that size.*" according to the fan-written [Wiki](https://en.battlestarwikiclone.org/wiki/Zephyr). I stand ready to downvote anyone who posts this without offering any supporting evidence

Comment: Because spinning is so much cooler than not spinning. Oh sorry, wrong franchise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*Science of Battlestar Galactica*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/6280654-the-science-of-battlestar-galactica) books (billed as the "*official guide to the science behind the Battlestar Galactica universe*")  discusses this in some detail. The implication is that the ship is either sufficiently old that it needed to generate gravity the old-fashioned way...

> Obviously Galactica docs not spin to simulate gravity, but a ship
> named Zephyr does. *Zephyr*, also known as the "*Ring Ship*" is one of
> the most prominent ships in the ragtag fleet. *Zephyr* seems to be
> quite the oddity within the Fleet, apparently being the only ship that
> creates artificial gravity in this way. This could imply that *Zephyr*
> is very old.

...or the ship is rather newer, but of an older *design*, intended to cash in on nostalgia.

> ..but if  that's the case then her FTL drive would have had to have
> been a retrofit. Perhaps, like a Chrysler PT Cruiser, the inner
> workings of the spacecraft are modern, but she has a "retro" exterior;
> "*Come experience what space travel was like for our Kobolian
> ancestors!*" *Zephyr* just may be a Colonial manifestation of steampunk.